# File download name in IE just "untitled.bmp" -- how to fix?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I'm using ASP.Net MVC3, and serving up files using this:

```
public class ByteResult : ActionResult
{
    public String ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }


    public ByteResult(byte[] sourceStream, String contentType)
    {
        Bytes = sourceStream;
        ContentType = contentType;

    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        response.ContentType = ContentType;

        var stream = new MemoryStream(Bytes);
        stream.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);
        stream.Dispose();       

    }
}
```

With photos embedded in a page using this method, when a user selects "save picture/image as ..." from a context menu, the save as dialog presents the file-name from the img src attribute for all browsers *except IE* (of course), which presents  "untitled.bmp" . yuck.

How do I fix for IE??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for you to be creating your own ActionResult to return byte content. It already exists, it's called [`FileResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx).

In your controller you would use the `File` method like so:

```
public ActionResult Do()
{
    return File(byteContentOrStream, "image/bmp", "yourfilename.bmp");
}
```

The 3rd parameter sets the file name in the content disposition.

Setting the content disposition yourself would work; but this is built into ASP.NET, and handles things according to the [RFC 2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt). For example, it handles proper escaping if the file name contains a quote.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to "suggest" a file name to the browser is by including the `Content-Disposition` [header in the response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses).  Something like this:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.bmp", someString));
```

Comment: This works in general, but not for IE. Could there be something else I'm missing for IE? Also, this has the un-wanted consequence of preventing the user from being able to open the image by itself in the browser, I.e. right-click "Open image in new tab" (Chrome) just goes straight to download.